# Changing field in PFUser from other PFUser, Parse iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, parse-platform, pfuser

I am attempting to change the value of another PFUser field, from another unauthenticated PFUser in Parse, however I cant seem to do so. I am attempting to increase the number of 'hours' of one user from another user. Here is how I am attempting to do so:

```
PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
PFACL *ACL = [PFACL ACLWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]];
[ACL setPublicReadAccess:YES];

PFUser *selectedUser = [self.formValues objectForKey:@"user"];
NSLog(@"User ID: %@", selectedUser.objectId);

PFObject *volunteerSheet = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"VolunteerSheet"];
volunteerSheet[@"userID"] = selectedUser.objectId;
volunteerSheet[@"fromID"] = currentUser.objectId;
volunteerSheet[@"volunteerTitle"] = [self.formValues objectForKey:@"title"];
volunteerSheet[@"location"] = [self.formValues objectForKey:@"location"];
volunteerSheet[@"volunteerHours"] = [self.formValues objectForKey:@"hours"];
volunteerSheet[@"volunteerDescription"] = [self.formValues objectForKey:@"description"];
volunteerSheet.ACL = ACL;
[volunteerSheet saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (succeeded) {
        // The object has been saved.
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];

        // Retrieve the object by id
        [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:selectedUser.objectId
                                     block:^(PFObject *user, NSError *error) {
                                         [user incrementKey:@"volunteerHours" byAmount:(NSNumber*)[self.formValues objectForKey:@"hours"]];
                                         [user saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                             if (succeeded) {
                                                 NSLog(@"Succeeded");
                                             }else{
                                                 NSLog(error.description);
                                             }
                                         }];
                                     }];

        NSLog(@"Saved");
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            UIAlertView * alert =[[UIAlertView alloc ] initWithTitle:@"Success!"
                                                             message:@"Hours Sent succesfully."
                                                            delegate:self
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                   otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Okay"];
            [alert show];
        }];
    } else {
        // There was a problem, check error.description
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",error.description);
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Users automatically have security put in place that disallow modifying another user (clps or alcs). Maybe consider moving to cloud code and calling use master key?

Answer (score 0):

Users have ACLs set up to only allow themselves to change their values. To get around this, you either have to change the ACL every time you create a user to allow any user to have write permissions for them (VERY RISKY AND NOT SECURE AT ALL), or you need to call a cloud function that calls `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()` , which overrides all permissions, and will enable you to make the changes. Obviously, you should still be doing some sort of security check to make sure that these changes are allowed / proper changes before putting them through.